# POST request always gives status 502 while querying Postgres

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, where-clause, pg

I'm trying to retrive some data from my database, and I'm experiencing a strange issue. My server-side is in Node.js, and i'm using 'pg' module for the connection to postgres, and 'express' for routing.

**Server-side code:**

```
router.post('/', function(req, res) {
    if (auth.hasValidSession(req)){
         var userc=auth.getUsername();//get current logged in user
         var client = new pg.Client(conString);
         client.connect();
         var superuser=client.query("SELECT superuser FROM Users WHERE username=$1;", [userc]);
        superuser.on('row', function(row){ 
            if(row.superuser==0){
                var query=client.query("SELECT x, y, z FROM myTable WHERE z=$1 OR t=FALSE ORDER BY y;", [userc]);
                query.on('row', function(row, result){
                    result.addRow(row);
                });
                query.on('end', function(result){
                    res.send(result);       
                });
            }else{
                var query=client.query("SELECT x, y, z FROM myTable ORDER BY y;");
                query.on('row', function(row, result){
                    result.addRow(row);
                });
                query.on('end', function(result){
                    res.send(result);       
                });
            }
        });
        superuser.on('end', function(){ client.end(); });
    }
});
```

Now, if the first query returns 1, the else block gets executed and all goes fine. If it returns 0 instead, I alwasy get status 502 (Bad Gateway).

If I change:

`var query=client.query("SELECT x, y, z FROM myTable WHERE z=$1 OR t=FALSE ORDER BY y;", [userc]);`

to:

`var query=client.query("SELECT x, y, z FROM myTable WHERE t=FALSE ORDER BY y;");`

this error disappears, as it should be related to the parameter. I assure that that variable is correct, it contains the right information. 
BTW, if I change the above query to:

`var query=client.query("SELECT x, y, z FROM myTable WHERE z=$1 ORDER BY y;", [userc]);`

I still have the same error, so it is not because of the OR clause.

Any suggestion to work around this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use on-error event?

```
query.on('error', function(error) {
  //handle the error
});
```

Try remove semicolon from end of query.

Comment: Semicolon removed, same issue. I usually handle errors, but how can this help in this situation?

Comment: I suspected query sintax but now I think that problem in `res.send`. How much row count return queries `SELECT x, y, z FROM myTable WHERE z=$1 OR t=FALSE ORDER BY y;`/`SELECT x, y, z FROM myTable WHERE z=$1 ORDER BY y;`   and `SELECT x, y, z FROM myTable WHERE t=FALSE ORDER BY y;")`?